# Interpretation of an interaction effect (ratio of odds ratios) when using effect coding

Tags: logistic, interaction, multilevel-analysis, odds-ratio, contrasts

I ran a multilevel logistic regression model using function `glmer` from R package lme4. All of my predictors are binary and I have used effect coding, i.e., coding -1 and 1. The model contains multiple interaction terms. I have computed odds ratios, but struggle to interpret the model's interaction effects. I know that the interaction terms represent ratios of odds ratios rather than odds ratios in themselves.

For instance, I have a variable agent type, which is coded -1 when the agent is a human being and 1 if it is an AI, as well as a variable called suffering, which is coded -1 when an industrial enterprise is affected by a decision and 1 if a hospital is affected. In order to interpret with regard to a reference group, I have multiplied the coefficients by 2. The estimated coefficient for agent is $2 \beta_{\text{Agent}} = 2 \cdot 1.07 = 2.14$, whereas that for suffering is $2 \beta_{\text{Suffering}} = 2 \cdot 3.82 = 7.64$. This produces odds of $OR_{\text{Agent}} = exp(2.14) = 8.48$ and $OR_{\text{Suffering}} = exp(7.64) = 2079.74$. The estimated coefficient for their interaction is $\beta_{\text{Agent \* Suffering}} = -0.97$ (without multiplication by 2).

Now my question is: How do I obtain an odds ratio for agent type when suffering is -1, as well as an odds ratio for agent type when suffering is 1. And how should I interpret these odds ratios? The following resource details how to do this when using dummy coding, but I am unsure on how to proceed when using effect coding: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/stata/seminars/deciphering-interactions-in-logistic-regression/ .